# How do I switch from root user to another user who has a nologin shell?

Tags: shell, users, nologin

I'm just learning linux.  Working as root, I created a new user called testuser.  I then changed testuser to a nologin shell.

Now I want to login as the testuser to see what a user with a nologin shell can/can't do.

I tried:    su testuser    and got:  This account is currently not available.
I tried:     su - testuser and got:
su: warning: cannot change directory to /home/testuser: No such file or directory
This account is currently not available.

How do I switch from root to a user with a nologin shell?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The point of the `nologin` shell is to prevent the user from logging in. Such a user may still use your server services like FTP, IMAP/POP3 and others but they won't be able to login e.g. using sshd or console, period.

> How do I switch from root to a user with a nologin shell?

```
sudo -u USERNAME /bin/bash
```

Will work but only root can do that.

Answer (score 5):

Artem's answer is good, but if `sudo` isn't available, it is also possible to use

```
su --shell /bin/bash USERNAME
```

From the `su` manual about the `-s`/`--shell` flag:

> If the target user has a restricted shell (i.e. the shell field of this user's entry in /etc/passwd is not listed in /etc/shells), then the **--shell** option or the **$SHELL** environment variable won't be taken into account, unless **su** is called by root.